# Magento 2.2 something went wrong with the subscription

Tags: magento2, newsletter

When customer tries to subscribe, magento return error something went wrong with the subscription. How can i fix it?
Mail function works on server correctly.

Comment: If it is not the core magento 2.2 problem, I guess it is problem with one of your custom module. try to deactivate them if you have an and see the problem still exist. Then you can investigate more about the problem.

Comment: Have you an error message? What is it?(check log if needed)

Answer (score 4):

I just changed the "Disable Email Communications" to yes in Magento 2 ( Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings > Disable Email Communications).
It works for me !

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me too.